# Templated constructor matching better than templated type conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

The following compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Point : public std::vector<double>
{
public:
    Point() = default;
};

class MyClass
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const { return T(); }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    Point test = myClass;

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I have a templated constructor, it does not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Point : public std::vector<double>
{
public:
    Point() = default;

    template <typename TVector>
    Point(const TVector& v)
    {
        (*this)[0] = v[0]; // compiler error on this line (saying no operator[] for MyClass, but the point is that this function is used instead of the type conversion function)
    }

};

class MyClass
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const { return T(); }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    Point test = myClass;

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot change the `Point` class (to add a second default constructor argument or anything like that), so is there a way to change only `MyClass` to make this work?

Comment: What compiler are you using? With gcc and clang I get ambiguous lookup.

Comment: @RyanHaining g++ 4.8.4

Comment: Templated arguments must match types exactly and do not allow type conversions. Unfrotunately, if you can't modify `Point`, you can't use `MyClass` like this.

Comment: @SergeyA If I have `operator Point() const { return Point(); }` it works even with the constructor present. So what is the difference between this and the templated `T()` where `T=Point`?

Comment: @DavidDoria a non-template is a better match than a template. When you have the two templates the compiler doesn't know which one to pick.

Comment: You should see this with a more recent compiler see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1639c556cdcea795)

Comment: @RyanHaining So this is a g++ implementation detail about why it is picking the constructor template over the type conversion template? I would have been less confused with an ambiguous overload compiler error.

Comment: @DavidDoria no it's ambiguous with [a more recent gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9b553f3b25b4f3d) as well. You should update your compiler, 4.8 is kind of old. Probably just caused by a older compiler bug.

Comment: Supply your `MyClass` with an `op[]`, then it would magically work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SFINAE to disable the constructor when there's no `operator[]` in the `TVector`

```
template <typename TVector, typename=decltype(std::declval<const TVector&>()[0])>
Point(const TVector& v)
```

When trying to evaluate the second `typename` the compiler will have to deduce what `TVector::operator[]` returns. When it can't, it throws out the constructor from overload resolution.

If you want to elaborate it a bit you can use `enable_if` to turn look a bit more explicit in `Point`

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasIndexOperator : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasIndexOperator<T,
          void_t<decltype(std::declval<const T&>()[0])>> : std::true_type {};
```

then your constructor becomes:

```
template <typename TVector, 
          typename=std::enable_if_t<HasIndexOperator<TVector>{}>>
      Point(const TVector& v)
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for the behavior OP is seeing. Thanks

Comment: @RyanHaining, your suggestion is correct, though you are not saying why :) It would be about leaving only copy constructor available, which would be non-templated.

Comment: @SergeyA `throws out the constructor` is why it's unambiguous. I'm assuming OP knows there's a copy constructor present already

Answer (score -1):

Template constructor like this

```
template <typename TVector>
    Point(const TVector& v)
```

would work as user-defined constructor, accepting anything which is not of type `Point` (that would still be handled by implictly defined copy constructor).

with

```
Point point = myclass;
```

compiler is finding templated constructor, doesn't perform any conversions and tries to call `operator[]` on the `MyClass`.

When you disable templated constructor (as Ryan suggests) for non-vectors, the only thing which is left is a non-template copy constructor, implictly declared as

```
Point(const Point& );
```

Compiler will perform conversion from `MyClass` to `Point` and everything will compile.

Comment: `both copy constructor and user-defined constructor`, that's not correct. The compiler sees this as a normal value constructor and will still generate a copy constructor

Comment: @SergeyA I guess I'm confused about why the copy constructor is involved here? Isn't `Point test = myClass;` using the conversion operator followed by the assignment operator?

Comment: @DavidDoria, no. In the syntax like that `type x = y` assignment operator is never playing any role. It is always copy constructor and, if type of y is not `type`, a value constructor of `type` from `y`.